# Ignore exceptions in a loop

Tags: python, exception, generator

I am writing a python program where I need to count the number of errors that come up in the loop.
every time an error is returned I add +1 to count and keep running until the program doesn't return an error.

```
def progName():
    count = 1
    while True:
        try:
           x,y = otherProgram()
           yeild [x,y,count]
        except:
           count+=1
```

What I want my program to do is to count the number of errors otherProgram() returns

Comment: Isn't that exactly what your code does? What's the issue? The only thing I see missing is a `return` or `break` following the (I think you meant) `yield` statement.

Comment: yes, I meant "yield", thanks.
but it gets stuck in an infinite loop for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your count should probably be initialized as 0. If you start with `count = 1` you are saying there has already been an error. So if you succeed on the first iteration it'll return x, y, 1 even if you had no errors.

If you want to end the loop on the FIRST success you get from otherProgram() you need to `return [x, y, count]`

If you want to continue to yield values from otherProgram() until some condition is met you need to fix your typo in yield and put in a termination condition to eventually end the loop when you get the number of values you want yielded.

Comment: I fixed the typo, but that's not the issue.
I want to return 1 if it succeeds on the first iteration.
For some reason it always gets stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: That's what I meant when talking about the need for a break condition. As written this will keep yielding forever. If you want it to stop the first time it gets a response instead of an error, change yield to return. If you want some number of answers or errors then you need to build in a condition like `if error > 20` then add a `break` to escape the loop